# Auto fill form using javascript - get data from datalist

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an autocomplete field that receives it's data from a database:

```
<datalist id="custlist">
    <?php
      $q_cust=mysql_query("select * from customer where rowstatus='0' order by id");          
                if (mysql_num_rows($q_cust)>0) {
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($q_cust)){
                        print '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                    }
                }

     ?>
 </datalist>
```

Below is my HTML for the codelist:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><h3>Field 1</h3></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input class="awesomplete" required="required" id="cust" name ="custnama" list="custlist" /></h3></td>
    <td></td>

</tr>
```

The autocomplete works fine (I'm using the awesomplete widget) and when I select one of the customer names, the input 1 field will automatically show the ID of the customer.

What I want to do is having another field, let's say "input 2" that will show the customer name when the user selects the ID from  the input 1 field.

Since I already stored the name as well on the data list, can I just get it from the datalist and show it in the input 2 field based on the value of input 1 using JavaScript?

If i can't do that please explain me the simplest way to get it done.